# How do I customize the .exe filename for Microsoft cmdline compiler, cl?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, output, rename, filenames

The only two options that I was able to find from googling are /OUT and /Fe, but neither works for me:

Using /Fe shows no error but no output file found in the current dir either:

```
C:\hands_on\C>cl /Fe:test.exe main.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out::test.exe
main.obj

C:\hands_on\C>ls
main.c  main.obj
```

Using /OUT gives errors:

```
C:\hands_on\C>cl /OUT:test.exe main.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Ot' with '/Os'
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Os' with '/Ot'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OU'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O:'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O.'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
main.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
```

The version of the compiler:

```
C:\hands_on\C>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

Comment: Interestingly, my question got down voted. Granted, it looked like a user error. But, I think part of the reason why I missed the trivial is the inconsistency in the command option format, that is, sometimes ":" is needed between the option and its value. I'm new to MS environment. Is there a document that explains about the general cmdline option syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
cl /Fetest.exe main.c
```

with no space or punctuation, or:

```
cl /Fe: test.exe main.c
```

with a colon and space.

You have a colon but no space:

```
cl /Fe:test.exe main.c
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fe-name-exe-file)